# How to get Jenkins to create SSH tunnel to new EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh, sonarqube

I have a local Jenkins and Sonar Cube setup.

Jenkins will spin up an EC2 instance (using ec2-plugin) and run an agent on it, but I now want the job to post data back to the Sonar Cube API.

I'm trying to avoid doing this by exposing the local Sonar Cube node to internet.

As my Jenkins instance can SSH to the spun up nodes, I was assuming I would be able to add a script that also creates an SSH tunnel to the node that would port forward the Sonar Cube port.

Does anyone know of a way I can get Jenkins to setup the SSH tunnel when it spins up an agent node?

I just want Jenkins to able to run the following command after spinning up the node.

`ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 me@my.agentnode.aws`

Answer (score 0):

"Agent command prefix" and/or "Root command prefix" (under AMI Type settings) can do this.
Agent command prefix specified as "-R 127.0.0.1:22222:localhost:22"
produce next extended connection command

```
INFO: Launching remoting agent (via SSH client process): ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /tmp/ec2_15656646762413263895.pem development@aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd -p 22 -R 127.0.0.1:22222:localhost:22  java  -jar ./remoting.jar -workDir .
```

and give us on node
 `TCP    127.0.0.1:22222        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`